# Какую библиотеку использовать в с++ для коннекта к бд

Tags: c++, sql

Какую библиотеку использовать в с++ для коннекта к бд. Ищу простую библиотеку для выполнение простеньких запросов. (орм не надо так как нет входных данных от пользователей).

Ораколовская не подходит, так как она для жителей рф недоступна. (скачать ее разумеется не могу)

БД внешняя,  MarianBD либо Mysql

Comment: К **какой** базе данных? Если хотите собственную и простенькую SQL — то посмотрите в сторону SQLite.

Comment: Видимо не корректно описал проблемму, соедениение с внешней базой MarianBD

Comment: Не совсем понятно. Вам нужен провайдер для БД? Или micro-ORM?

Comment: мне нужен инструмент (либа) для взаимодействия с внешней бд

Comment: [это](https://mariadb.com/downloads/?tab=connectors&group=connectors_dataaccess&product=C%2B%2B+connector) [отсюда](https://mariadb.com/docs/connect/programming-languages/cpp/install/) чем не подходит?

Comment: Это то что надо, осталось понять как выделить ваш ответ как решение...

Comment: @Red, напишите ответ сами (это разрешено правлами) (если хотите, может упомянуть там  мой комментарий)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Для MariaDB оптимальное решение [MariaDB Connector/C++](https://mariadb.com/docs/connect/programming-languages/cpp/install/) с скомпилимораными библеотеками под порядка 10 платформ. Спасибо [@avp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/232/avp)
2. Для совсем простых решений без подключение к внешним бд. [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/index.html). Спасибо [@Bloody.cpp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/500890/bloody-cpp)
3. Для Mysql есть официальная библеотека от оракл [Connector/C++ 8.0.30](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/) Но к сожалению из рф скачать нельзя.
4. Нашел интересный репозиторий на гитхабе. [OCILIB - C and C++ Drivers for Oracle](https://github.com/vrogier/ocilib)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал вам SQLite3. Вот ссылка на официальный сайт: [кляц](https://sqlite.org/index.html). И ещё: [кляц 1](https://habr.com/ru/post/149356/) [кляц 2](https://habr.com/ru/post/149390/) [кляц 3](https://habr.com/ru/post/149635/). Правда не знаю к какой базе вы хотите подключаться. Подозреваю, что вам просто нужно сохранять какую-то информацию.

Comment: Видимо не корректно описал проблемму, соедениение с внешней базой MarianBD

Comment: Почему вы не можете воспользоваться VPN для скачивания "ораколовской" библиотеки?? @Red